# Refactoring a rake task to be less repetitive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring, rake

Pretty new to Ruby on Rails here. I'm trying to refactor a rake task. It works fine but I think it could be more concise although I'm not sure where to start. Please offer suggestions on how I might improve this code.

```
task assign_position_to_items: :environment do
  pos = 0
  MyObject.find(param).checklist_item_sections.order(:id).each do | item |
    item.update(position: pos)
    pos += 1
    item.check_list_items.order(:id).each do | itm |
      itm.update(position: pos)
      pos += 1
      itm.inspection_responses.order(:id).each do | it |
        it.update(position: pos)
        pos += 1
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable#each_with_index` see [api docs](https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_6_3/Enumerable/each_with_index) to dry this up a bit, and also you can loop over the relation methods to dry it further. Finally you can pass the increment method as a value directly.

```
task assign_position_to_items: :environment do
  MyObject.find(param).checklist_item_sections.order(:id).each_with_index do |item, pos|
    item.update(position: pos)
    [:check_list_items, :inspection_responses].each do |method|
      pos += 1
      item.send(method).order(:id) do |children|
        children.upate(position: pos += 1)
      end
    end
  end
end
```